# Mathematical term for not taking a value while approaching a point

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta

On [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_of_compositions_of_functions) they describe a condition for the composite limit rule:

> $g$ does not take the value $b$ near $a$.  That is, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|g(x)-b|>0$

This is mighty similar to a delta/epsilon limit, except instead of $<\epsilon$ it's $>0$.  Is there a word for this, or is "does not take value near" the most common expression?

Comment: I don’t think I’ve never needed to use this phrase before. I don’t know of a better way to say it than “does not take the value $b$ near $a$”. In fact, that seems like a very clear way to say it.

Comment: Is there a limit notation way to express this?

Comment: By the way, instead of saying $| g(x) - b | > 0$ they should just say $g(x) \neq b$.

Comment: I've never needed this phrase, either, but "$g(x)$ **avoids** $b$, for $x$ near $a$" seems like a concise way to put it.